Insert array of structs using Debezium Jdbc Sink Connector into Postgres
I'm using io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector to extract documents from MongoDB and send to Kafka. Every event has the folowing structure:
{
  "schema": {
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "name": "io.debezium.data.Json",
        "version": 1,
        "field": "before"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "name": "io.debezium.data.Json",
        "version": 1,
        "field": "after"
      },
      {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
          {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "string",
              "optional": false
            },
            "optional": true,
            "field": "removedFields"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": true,
            "name": "io.debezium.data.Json",
            "version": 1,
            "field": "updatedFields"
          },
          {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "struct",
              "fields": [
                {
                  "type": "string",
                  "optional": false,
                  "field": "field"
                },
                {
                  "type": "int32",
                  "optional": false,
                  "field": "size"
                }
              ],
              "optional": false,
              "name": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.changestream.truncatedarray",
              "version": 1
            },
            "optional": true,
            "field": "truncatedArrays"
          }
        ],
        "optional": true,
        "name": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.changestream.updatedescription",
        "version": 1,
        "field": "updateDescription"
      },
      {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "version"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "connector"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "name"
          },
          {
            "type": "int64",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "ts_ms"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": true,
            "name": "io.debezium.data.Enum",
            "version": 1,
            "parameters": {
              "allowed": "true,last,false,incremental"
            },
            "default": "false",
            "field": "snapshot"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "db"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": true,
            "field": "sequence"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "rs"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "collection"
          },
          {
            "type": "int32",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "ord"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": true,
            "field": "lsid"
          },
          {
            "type": "int64",
            "optional": true,
            "field": "txnNumber"
          },
          {
            "type": "int64",
            "optional": true,
            "field": "wallTime"
          }
        ],
        "optional": false,
        "name": "io.debezium.connector.mongo.Source",
        "field": "source"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "op"
      },
      {
        "type": "int64",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "ts_ms"
      },
      {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "id"
          },
          {
            "type": "int64",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "total_order"
          },
          {
            "type": "int64",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "data_collection_order"
          }
        ],
        "optional": true,
        "name": "event.block",
        "version": 1,
        "field": "transaction"
      }
    ],
    "optional": false,
    "name": "data.adb.shipments3.Envelope"
  },
  "payload": {
    "before": null,
    "after": "{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"6613f1b16344a5046d883b63\"},\"id\": 100500,\"shipment_id\": 123,\"orders\": [{\"id\": 14,\"quantity\": 56},{\"id\": 15,\"quantity\": 51,\"size\": 171717}],\"shipmentsIds\": [],\"properties\": {\"p1\": 1,\"p2\": \"at1\"}}",
    "updateDescription": null,
    "source": {
      "version": "2.5.0.Final",
      "connector": "mongodb",
      "name": "data",
      "ts_ms": 0,
      "snapshot": "true",
      "db": "adb",
      "sequence": null,
      "rs": "rs0",
      "collection": "shipments3",
      "ord": -1,
      "lsid": null,
      "txnNumber": null,
      "wallTime": null
    },
    "op": "r",
    "ts_ms": 1713185302186,
    "transaction": null
  }
}

Every document has array of structs orders and then I try to insert documents into Postgres using io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector I get the following error:
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Cannot list fields on non-struct type
2024-04-15T13:59:50.299689999Z  at org.apache.kafka.connect.data.ConnectSchema.fields(ConnectSchema.java:179)
2024-04-15T13:59:50.299693180Z  at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.SinkRecordDescriptor$Builder.applyNonKeyFields(SinkRecordDescriptor.java:473)
2024-04-15T13:59:50.299696574Z  at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.SinkRecordDescriptor$Builder.readSinkRecordNonKeyData(SinkRecordDescriptor.java:467)
2024-04-15T13:59:50.299700283Z  at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.SinkRecordDescriptor$Builder.build(SinkRecordDescriptor.java:313)
2024-04-15T13:59:50.299704970Z  at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcChangeEventSink.buildRecordSinkDescriptor(JdbcChangeEventSink.java:178)
2024-04-15T13:59:50.299708278Z

Seems like sink connector can't process complex structures (array) from the message.
My question - is it possible to insert json part of this message payload.after into Postgres like jsonb structure?
